# Unable to install mongodb

Tags: server, software-installation, mongodb

I try to install mongodb on server machine(Ubuntu server) using [installing mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

When i used `sudo apt-get update`, i found `404 Not Found` for many urls as the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

I skipped this problem, i run the next command `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`, but i got the following errors:

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-45-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.5.0-45-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.5.0-45-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.5.0-39-generic (3.5.0-39.60) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-45-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-39-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-39-generic
```

And

```
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Errors were encountered 

while processing:
 linux-image-3.5.0-45-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-39-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-40-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-41-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-44-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-45-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I found mongodb is installed, and its packages, but i want to know why these errors occurred ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: It also looks like one of your disks is full (possibly just /boot if it is a separate partition) - you will want to fix that before you upgrade

Answer (score 0):

The 404 errors are pretty easy to handle:

> Support for Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal officially ended on May 16, 2014.

If you are still using 12.10, we cannot help you.
You should really consider upgrading:
[Instructions for upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)